# Border Select keyframes in Action Editor

Tags: animation

I am having trouble selecting multiple keyframes in the action editor spread over multiple channels. I have tried with all channels selected/deselected but with no luck. Is there a trick in order to get border select working across multiple channels.

Here is my attempt to border select, after which I individually select keyframes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you maybe accidentally using "B" + "Middle Mouse Button" instead of "B" + "Left Mouse Button"? Did you configure anything in the mouse settings?

Comment: Nope. B + Left mouse button. In my setting I have selected using the left mouse button for selecting instead of the right. I have tried both options but with no avail.

Comment: Do you have a mouse with 3 buttons (with a middle mouse button/Roller) or are you using laptop buttons?

Comment: Can you specify your hardware (laptop, keyboard, mouse) or can you upload your .blend to have a look... upload: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have added a link to the file. I am using a standard 3 button mouse.

Comment: Really don't know why "B" does not work. But "Alt + B" does work sometimes. But selects to much...

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpin the action in NLA editor.

[image: Unpin here]

It will then "un-timeremap" your action and allow you to select with B.

Not sure if "feature or bug", will ask Aligorith or a dev.